# bash script that uses nc for telnet reports ": command not found OK"

Tags: bash

If I go to a bash prompt and run the following command (to flush memcached):

```
echo "flush_all" | /usr/bin/nc 172.16.198.130 11211
```

it works and returns "OK".

If I put that same command in a one-line bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
`echo "flush_all" | /usr/bin/nc 172.16.198.130 11211`
```

I get the following output:

```
: command not found OK
```

Is it trying to process "OK" as a second command? How can I prevent this (short of redirecting to /dev/null)?

Comment: remove the backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the backticks around the commands, you're attempting to execute the output of:
`echo "flush_all" | /usr/bin/nc 172.16.198.130 11211`
In your case "OK"
like already mentioned in the comments just remove the backticks.

Comment: Wow, now I feel dumb.  :)  In a prior version of the script the output was being saved to a local variable, so I had the ticks. I removed the variable logic bug left the backticks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This:
    #!/bin/sh
    `echo bob`
    `echo jim`

Is identical to me doing this on the terminal:

```
# bob
bob: command not found
# jim
jim: command not found
```

Remove the backticks.